# Testing exception thrown by Project Reactor onErrorMap

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

I'm trying test catching an exception (`kotlin.Exception`) thrown by a `Mono`, which is then caught, and a new exception thrown (`MyException`).

The following snippet fails ...

```
class MyException : Exception("My Exception")
assertThrows<MyException> {
     Mono.fromCallable { throw Exception() }
         .onErrorMap { MyException() }
         .subscribe()
}
```

... with the following error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown ==> 
Expected :<com.company.project.service.SomeServiceTest$foobar$MyException> 
Actual   :<reactor.core.Exceptions.ErrorCallbackNotImplemented>
```

however, the following passes

```
assertThrows<RuntimeException> {
    Mono.fromCallable { throw Exception() }
        .onErrorMap { RuntimeException() }
        .subscribe()
}
```

and I'm unsure why. Except that I am using a custom exception, I see no difference.

I also tried using `block()`, with similar results:

```
class MyException : Exception("My Exception")
assertThrows<MyException> {
    Mono.fromCallable { throw Exception() }
            .onErrorMap { MyException() }
            .block()
}
```

different exception:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown ==> 
Expected :<com.company.project.service.SomeServiceTest$foobar$MyException> 
Actual   :<reactor.core.Exceptions.ReactiveException>
```

Comment: The `assertThrows<RuntimeException>` passes because `ErrorCallbackNotImplemented` extends RuntimeException.  I think if you look further in the debugger, the exception that's thrown there is still `ErrorCallbackNotImplemented`.  I -think- what you would want to do is add an error clause in your `.subscribe` method and in there you will likely get the exception you are expecting, and you can re-throw it if you want.

Comment: Thanks @jolo, you are correct - the test passing is a "red herring", as you rightly noticed `ErrorCallbackNotImplemented` extends `RuntimeException`. I think the problem here is that `.subscribe()` doesn't block and return the exception itself, which would need to be achieved by passing a callback function like you say. So, I think using `.block()` is more appropriate. It's a bit strange that this returns `ReactiveException`, not `MyException` however.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to test a Publisher (Mono/Flux), you should use [StepVerifier](https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.html). Don't forget that when you use the subscribe method, it doesn't block the thread. This can lead to that your test can sometimes pass and sometimes not because the test(main) thread can terminate before your tested stream (Mono) is done.

```
class MyException : Exception("My Exception")

@Test
fun `correct exception mapping`() {
    val theMonoWeWantToTest = Mono
        .fromCallable { throw Exception() }
        .onErrorMap { MyException() }

    theMonoWeWantToTest
        .test() // Kotlin's extension function for Reactor's StepVerifier
        .expectError(MyException::class.java)
        .verify()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `assertThrows<RuntimeException>` passes because `ErrorCallbackNotImplemented` extends `RuntimeException`. I think if you look further in the debugger, the exception that's thrown there is still `ErrorCallbackNotImplemented`. I -think- what you would want to do is add an error clause in your .subscribe method and in there you will likely get the exception you are expecting, and you can re-throw it if you want.